# Range bug after upgrading Android Studio - Value must be ≤ 1.0 (was 100) less

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

After Android Studio upgrade to version 3.0 I get the following warning: "Value must be ≤ 1.0 (was 100) less."

[image]

But the project is normally compiled. What's wrong with the number 100?

I drew attention to this because the Android Studio marks this as an error, not an ordinary warning.

[image]

Comment: What is `ColorUtils`? What annotation does `calculateLuminance()` have on its return value? When you use Ctrl+F1 to read more about the error, what does it tell you? If you use Alt+Enter to bring up the quick-fix menu for this error, does it offer a `@SuppressLint` option, and if so, what Lint check does it offer to suppress?

Comment: @CommonsWare android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils.calculateLuminance() return float between 0.0 and 1.0. Full error description: "Some parameters are required to in a particular numerical range; this check makes sure that arguments passed fall within the range. For arrays, Strings and collections this refers to the size or length.". @SuppressLint("Range") works, but why did not cause such problems before? Nothing has changed in the code.

Comment: Fixed for 3.1 Canary 5 by If any issue persists, please report at Google issue tracker they will re-open to examine. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69366129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in lint (https://issuetracker.google.com/69366129).
It has been fixed for 3.1 Canary 5.

Answer (score 0):

Odd — for some reason, I'm not seeing `android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils` in the JavaDocs. Regardless, based on source code, the return value has `@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)`, which is where the Lint error is getting its data from.

In terms of why you are seeing an error, that feels like a Lint bug. You might consider filing an issue with a reproducible test case.

In terms of why you are seeing an error *now*, each new version of Android Studio has new Lint rules, some of which may have bugs.

Comment: Yes, it's probably a Lint bug.
PS: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html

Comment: @Mikhail: OK, then the search has a bug. If you try using the search field and start typing, you won't find `ColorUtils`.